If $\alpha \neq \beta$ be ordinals and $\alpha \in \beta$ then $\alpha \subset \beta$

If $\alpha \neq \beta$ be ordinals with $\in$ being the ordering and $\alpha \subset \beta$ then $\alpha \in \beta$.

Proof:
I don't get why $\alpha = Seg(\beta, \gamma)$. Here, $\gamma = min(\beta - \alpha)$(least element). And,
$$Seg(\beta, \gamma) = \{\delta \in \beta: \delta \in \gamma\}$$
The key is "$\alpha$ is transitive". But this makes no sense. It is true that $Seg(\beta, \gamma) \subset \alpha$ since
$$Seg(\beta, \gamma) \subset \alpha$$
since otherwise there exists $\delta \in \beta$ wtih $\delta \notin \alpha$ and $\delta \in \gamma$, which is absurd since $\gamma$ is the least. But why
$$\alpha \subset Seg(\beta, \gamma)$$
? I have no idea.

This is true for von Neumann ordinals.  But that is not the only way to formalize ordinals.

Take $\delta\in\alpha$. Notice that it is sufficient to prove that $\delta\in\gamma$. By trichotomy, we must have $\delta\in\gamma$, $\delta=\gamma$, and $\gamma\in\delta$ but the last two options are impossible. Can you see why?

$\alpha$ is ordinal. So, $\gamma \in \delta$ and $\delta \in \alpha$ implies $\gamma \in \alpha$.
